# Laravel 5.1 Disturbance with Virtual Host on Local Server

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've just installed Laravel 5.1 and I've created a Virtual host for it 'www.laravelproperty.com' whose root directory is 'larvel-property/public/index.php'.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin m.khuramj@live.com
   ServerName laravelproperty.com
   ServerAlias www.laravelproperty.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/property-project/public/index.php

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also changed the 'application URL' in config/app.php (but that affects artisan cli). I've included HTML and Form classes. When I try to include css using the following syntax in my master template head:

```
{!!HTML::style('css/boostrap.min.css') !!}
```

it links the file but nothing is implemented. While in firebug it shows file 'bootstrap.min.css' with 0 rules and it's url is shown as 'www.laravelproperty.com/css/bootstrap.min.scs'.
But when I include it from the Internet 'bootstrap' with the following syntax:

```
{!!Html::style('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css')!!}
```

it works, it means there is a pathe problem, but I'm unable to fix it. Can some one help me in this regard? What is the thing I'm unable to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is the following:

```
{!!HTML::style(URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}
```

or

```
{!!HTML::style(asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}
```

This will essentially create the correct URL to your asset (your css file in this case) and will put it in a html-style tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve the problem. Thanks for the answer LeShadow. 
The problem was that I was using 'index.php' file in my root directory like this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/property-project/public/index.php
```

Just remove '/index.php' from the above line (which is the part of my virtual host file) and will become:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/property-project/public
```

Well, this has solved my problem.